# How do I refer to a view controller in a subclass?

Tags: objective-c

Hey all, I'm currently teaching myself Objective C and I'm kind of stuck.

I'm building a backgammon game and I have a subclass, "Piece", which is being initialized, repeatedly, in BackGammonViewController.

In BackGammonViewController, if I do this:

```
UIImage *myImage = [ UIImage imageNamed: @"white-piece.png" ];

UIImageView *myImageView = [ [ UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage: myImage ];
[self.view addSubview:myImageView];
[myImageView release];
```

The image appears. However, I want to do this within my "piece" class. How do I refer to the "self.view" from within the piece class? Do I need to pass a reference to the view, into the "piece class" ? Or is there a global reference I can call from within the "piece class" ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid reaching across classes like that by accessing your controller's view from the `Piece`.

Instead, the `Piece` should be a subclass of `UIView` which adds the image as a subview to itself when it is `init`ed with a frame:

```
[self addsubview:myImageView];
```

You add it as a subview to `self` because `self` inherits from `UIView`. Thus `self` "IS" a `UIView`.

Then, just add the piece as a subview of your controller's view.

Comment: So, in Piece.h, I'd change it to be: 

"@interface Piece : UIView {", 



and then in Piece.m do "[self.view addSubview:myImageView];"

? 

This is throwing me an error (error: request for member 'view' in something not a structure or union). Thanks for your help Chris!